# ftp multiple new files using wildcards

Tags: linux, ftp, wildcard

I was wondering if there is a way to use ftp to only get files that match a wildcard if the files is newer than the local copy?

I know I can use mget * but that will get everything and I only want to get the file(s) if they are newer than a local copy.  Is there a way to use mget in combination with newer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) which will do this for you.